# Redefining a list of variables in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I can define many variables together as follows:

```
(match-define (list a b c) (list 1 2 3))
a
b
c
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
>
```

But how can I redefine these variables again later in the program?

Essentially, I am looking for a 'match-redefine' function or macro.

Following does not work:

```
(set! (list a b c) (list 10 20 30))
set!: not an identifier in: (list a b c)
```

I also tried map function:

```
> (map set! (list a b c) (list 5 6 7))
. set!: bad syntax in: set!
>
```

Do I need to write a function for it or is there some simple built-in method?

Edit: I tried following match-redefine macro, written on the lines of swap macro on https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html :

```
(match-define (list a b c) (list 1 2 3))

(println "------- sl --------")
(define sl (list a b c))
(println sl)

(println "------- vl --------")
(define vl (list 5 6 7))
(println vl)

(define-syntax-rule (match-redefine slist vlist)
  (for ((i slist) (j vlist))
    (set! i j)
  )
)

(println "----- expecting sl to become 5 6 7 ----------")
(match-redefine sl vl)
(println sl)
```

But it does not work. The output is:

```
"------- sl --------"
'(1 2 3)
"------- vl --------"
'(5 6 7)
"----- expecting sl to become 5 6 7 ----------"
'(1 2 3)
```

Edit: I found that match-let allows reallocation using lists:

```
(define a 1)
(define b 2)
(define c 3)

(match-let ((  (list a b c) (list 100 200 300)  ))
  (println a)
  (println b)
  (println c)
)
```

Output:

```
100
200
300
```

But it is not a 'define' or 'set!' for use over all of remaining source file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is "Redefining a list of variables in Racket".
The answer is that you can't!

You can have a list of values, but not a list of variables.
The expression `(list a b c)` evaluates to a list of three elements:

```
> (define a 1)
> (define b 2)
> (define c 3)
> (list a b c)
(list 1 2 3)
```

In Racket you can give a name to a value:

```
> (define xs (list 1 2 3))
> xs
(list 1 2 3)
```

Now the variable `xs` is refers to a value (a list of three numbers).

You can change what a variable refers to using `set!`:

```
> (set! xs (list 5 6 7))
(list 5 6 7)
```

If you want to change three variables at the same time, you can use `set-values!`.

```
> (set!-values (a b c) (values 8 9 10))
> a
8
```

The names `a`, `b` and `c` are identifiers - names that occur in your program.
This means you can *not* put them in a list.

Due to symbols one can get confused:

```
 > '(a b c)
 '(a b c)
```

Here the names `a,b,c` are not variables or identifiers. They are symbols.

A list of strings is printed like this:

```
> '("a" "b" "c")
'("a" "b" "c")
```

Symbols on the other hand are printed without any character around them.

If you have a symbol `a` and want to set the variable whose name is `a` you can use `eval` - but it is very rare that using `eval` is a good idea. I'll leave to  you to google the phrase "eval is evil racket".

EDIT: Added a missing not.

Comment: Can't we do it using a macro? How does swap work on this page https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html ?

Comment: Perhaps a new question in which you explain the bigger picture?

Comment: Macros like `swap` can work because macros don't deal with values, they deal with syntax. Forms like `set!` don't deal with values either, and neither do macros like `match-define`. The `(list a b c)` in a `match-define` form isn't a value. To `match-define`, it's a piece of syntax that happens to look just like a `list` function call.

Answer (score 3):

@soegaard is absolutely right. Lists are values, and they contain other values, not variables.

However, if I'm reading your question right, it's possible that you just want a nice syntax for pattern-matching to mutate some variables according to where they appear in the pattern, something like:

```
> (define a 1)
> (define b 2)
> (define c 3)
> (match-set! (list a b c) (list 10 20 30))
> a
10
> b
20
> c
30
```

It *is* possible to do that, using a macro that does a [`local-expand`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29) on a constructed [`match-define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match-define%29%29) form. This is somewhat dependent on the internal implementation details of [`match-define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match-define%29%29) though, so I wouldn't recommend using it in real code.

This macro will have to do some extra compile-time manipulation transforming [`define-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html#%28part._multiple-values%29) (which [`match-define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match-define%29%29) will expand into) into [`set!-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/set_.html#%28part._.Multiple_.Values__set_-values%29), so it's a good idea to write a helper function within a [`begin-for-syntax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._begin-for-syntax%29%29) to do that transformation.

```
#lang racket
(require syntax/parse/define
         (for-syntax syntax/parse ; for syntax-parse
                     syntax/stx)) ; for stx-map

(begin-for-syntax
  ;; defs->set!s : Syntax -> Syntax
  ;; A helper function for match-set!, to transform define-values into set!-values
  (define (defs->set!s defs)
    (syntax-parse defs #:literals (begin define-values)
      [(define-values [x ...] expr)
       #'(set!-values [x ...] expr)]
      [(begin defs ...)
       #:with (set!s ...) (stx-map defs->set!s #'(defs ...))
       #'(begin set!s ...)])))
```

Then the macro needs to construct a [`match-define`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match-define%29%29) form, then use [`local-expand`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29) to expand that into the [`define-values`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html#%28part._multiple-values%29) forms, and use the `defs->set!s` helper function on those.

```
(define-syntax-parser match-set!
  [(match-set! pat expr)
   #:with defs
   (local-expand #'(match-define pat expr) (syntax-local-context) #f)
   (defs->set!s #'defs)])
```

Using it works exactly like the examples above.

Comment: I found that match-set! (also match-let) works with (list a b c) but not if such lists have been named. For example, following  does not work: (define alist (list a b c)) (match-set! alist (list 10 20 30)). Though alist gets value of (list 10 20 30), a b and c remain unchanged. Can this be corrected by your elegant coding!

Comment: I think I've told you in a different comment, but the `(list a b c)` within a `match` form isn't a value at all. Neither is the `x` in `(set! x 5)`, or the `(list a b c)` in a `match-set!` form. If you wrote `(set! alist (list 10 20 30))`, would you expect `a`, `b`, or `c` to change?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should read the [Top-Level Variables](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Top-.Level_.Variables%29), [Objects and Imperative Update](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Objects_and_.Imperative_.Update%29), and [Local Variables](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Procedure_.Applications_and_.Local_.Variables%29), sections of the Racket documentation, which have good examples to explain these concepts

Answer (score 2):

To set and update multiple variables at one use `define-values` and `set!-values`:

```
(define-values (a b c) (values 1 2 3))
(set!-values (a b c) (values 2 3 4))
```

[`match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=matcj#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29) is not supposed to be used as a general way of setting variables but a way to match structure and destructure them into bindings.

`map` will not work on either since it happens in the runtime and not compile time.  You can hack it to work if you introduce your own type of variables.

```scm
#lang racket
(require srfi/26)

(define-values (runtime-bounded? runtime-value? runtime-set! runtime-get runtime-set-values! runtime-get-values)
  (let ((vars (make-hasheq)))
    ;; a unique value to be our miss
    (define fail (list "empty"))

    ;; check if we have a symbol
    (define (bounded? name)
      (hash-has-key? vars name))

    ;; check if a value is not our miss
    (define (value? val)
      (not (eq? fail val)))

    ;; single operations
    (define (set! name val)
      (hash-set! vars name val))
    (define (get name (default fail))
      (hash-ref vars name default))

    ;; list operations
    (define (set-values! names values)
      (for-each set! names values))
    (define (get-values names (default fail))
      (map (cut get <> default) names))

    ;; bind them to global symbols
    (values bounded? value? set! get set-values! get-values)))
```

It works like this:

```
(define lst-names '(a b c))
(define lst-values '(1 2 3))
(runtime-set-values! lst-names lst-values)
(runtime-get-values '(a b c))               ; (1 2 3)
(runtime-get 'a)                            ; ==> 1
(runtime-set! 'a 10)
(runtime-get 'x 1337)                       ; 1337
(runtime-get-values '(a x) #f)              ; (10 #f)

;; use map/for-each to set something
(for-each (cut runtime-set! <> 10) '(x y z)) ; sets x y z to 10
```

This is flat, but with some tweaking one might even be able to make this mimic lexical structure as well. Then again one might consider [parameters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/parameters.html?q=parameters) instead.

The performance would be worse than using actual variables but in most cases you might not it that at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [set!-values](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/set_.html?q=set!#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._set%21-values%29%29).

```
(match-define (list a b c) (list 1 2 3))
(set!-values (a b c) (values 10 20 30))
```

Comment: I have 2 lists : (list a b c) and (list 10 20 30) . How do I convert them to (a b c) and (values 10 20 30)?